# Trying to make a cmd game/sim

Tags: cmd, calculator, simulator

I'm trying to make a cmd game/sim. but the numbers won't change! I feel like such a scrub and I'm probably a massive idiot... Here is all the code, if you want to yell at me use

```
*YELLING* text here *YELLING*
```

All the code:

```
@echo off
title Gold Economics Sim. 2014

goto info

:info
set/a money=100000
set/a gold=10
set/a gldpk=31300
set/a golda=0
set/a moneya=0

goto begin

->:tstpg
->cls
->echo You have %money% Dollar
->echo You have %gold% KG gold
->echo The gold price is %gldpk% Dollar
->echo How much gold do you want?
->
->:tstpgc
->set/p tstpgc=""
->goto buytst
->
->:buytst
->set/a golda=gold+testpgc
->set/a moneya=money-testpgc*gldph
->
->goto tstpg2
->
->:tstpg2
->echo You have %moneya% Dollar
->echo You have %golda% KG gold
->echo The gold price is %gldpk% Dollar
->pause

:begin
cls
echo ==============================================================================
echo                                  Main Menu
echo ==============================================================================
echo  Welcome to Gold Economics Sim. 2014! The goal of this 'Game' is to earn
echo  as much money as you can in three-four years. There's also a custom mode where
echo  you can edit all the game settings! Hope you enjoy this preview game!
echo(
echo  Type "start"          to begin
echo  Type "options"        to change the settings
echo  Type "help"           to get help
echo  Type "quit" or "exit" to quit
echo(
echo V0.1
echo ==============================================================================

:beginc
set/p beginc=""
if "%beginc%"=="start" goto start
if "%beginc%"=="help" goto help
if "%beginc%"=="options" goto options
if "%beginc%"=="quit" exit
if "%beginc%"=="exit" exit
if "%beginc%"=="test page" goto tstpg 
if "%beginc%"=="clean" goto begin
echo Sorry, but I don't understand that.
goto beginc
```

I'm sorry if it's just a stupid really small mistake, I frustrated about this for an hour and couldnt fix it, so I hope that someone here can maybe fix it? I will put you in the credits if you helped, tried to fix it, fixed it or didnt fix it.

Edit: I'm sorry that I didn't really explain my question/problem that well, I'm not using the `if "%beginc%"=="options" goto options` thing yet. That was my mistake. The problem is that the code with these arrows (->) won't change.

Comment: there is no start label in your code: if "%beginc%"=="start" goto start

Comment: `if /i "%beginc%"=="text" ` add the `/i` to your compares too, and then letter case doesn't matter.

Comment: woow I didn't know that foxidrive, thx. You've fixed a problem that I had with another game!

Answer (score 0):

The single biggest issue is the missing destinations.

```
if "%beginc%"=="start" goto start
if "%beginc%"=="help" goto help
if "%beginc%"=="options" goto options
if "%beginc%"=="quit" exit
if "%beginc%"=="exit" exit
if "%beginc%"=="test page" goto tstpg 
if "%beginc%"=="clean" goto begin
```

`:start`, `:options` and `:help` haven't been defined a anywhere in the code.

As for whether Windows Batch is good language for anything, see the [batch language solutions](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Batch_File) on RosettaCode.

Comment: I'm sorry that i didn't really say what my problem was, I was frustrated and tired and didn't really check everything. I'm not using the :start,... things yet. Just :tstpg for testing. Thanks and sorry.

Comment: Hey, no problem. Happens to all of us.

Answer (score 0):

Ooh, i see, you don't have any proper if variables for example:
if you wanted to make the person start when they input PLAY you need this:

```
echo THE FRAME UP HERE!
set /p P1=
if %P1% equ PLAY goto PLAY_1
if %P1% neq PLAY goto MENU
```

(the P1 is the variable that will be called)

(The neq one isn't necessary but it allows you to make typos and not kill cmd.exe)